# Webstorm/IDEA JavaScript function line counts

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, refactoring, webstorm

I'm trying to find a way in IntelliJ IDEA/Webstorm to inspect a large JavaScript project and show line counts of functions.  Is there any such feature or plugin available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable inspection `JavaScript | JavaScript function metrics | Overly long function` in `Settings | Inspections`, set target line count and trigger `Analyze | Run inspection by name` on your project to get all resuls in one place. But it seems anonymous functions are not reported.